# Loading screen before page appears flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, screen, future

The Loading screen is not showing before the homepage appears.  here is my code for the screen with the button.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:instacash/screens/Customer%20Onboarding/onboarding/slider_page1.dart';
import 'package:instacash/screens/Customer%20Onboarding/onboarding/slider_page2.dart';
import 'package:instacash/screens/Customer%20Onboarding/onboarding/slider_page3.dart';
import 'package:instacash/screens/Customer%20Onboarding/onboarding/slider_page4.dart';
import 'package:instacash/screens/Customer%20Onboarding/onboarding/slider_page5.dart';
import 'package:instacash/screens/loading.dart';

class Landing extends StatefulWidget {
const Landing({super.key});

 @override
// ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
 _LandingState createState() => _LandingState();
  }

  class _LandingState extends State<Landing> {
  int _currentPage = 0;
  final PageController _controller = PageController();

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
  const SliderPage1(),
  const SliderPage2(),
  const SliderPage3(),
  const SliderPage4(),
  const SliderPage5(),
  ];

  _onchanged(int index) {
  setState(() {
  _currentPage = index;
   });
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        onPageChanged: _onchanged,
        controller: _controller,
        itemCount: _pages.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          return _pages[index];
        },
      ),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: List<Widget>.generate(_pages.length, (int index) {
                return AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    height: 10,
                    width: (index == _currentPage) ? 30 : 10,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 5, vertical: 30),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: (index == _currentPage)
                            ? Colors.blue.shade900
                            : Colors.white));
              })),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 70,
          ),
          Row(
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                        check(context),
                      },
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: 50.0,
                  minWidth: 300,
                  elevation: 10.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                  child: Text(
                    'Get Started',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black45,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  )),
              //const SizedBox(height: 50.0,)
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}

 Future check(context) async {
 await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
 const Loading();
  })
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homepage');
 }
```

I am trying to make the loading screen in the future method show for about 3 seconds before the home screen appears but it just keeps navigating to the homepage. The future check method has the loading screen and the homepage screen to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` for your loading screen by also giving `Duration(seconds:3)`. In order to show that loading in whole screen, you need to place it before `Scaffold` widget of the landing page

Comment: i tried that but it got stuck at the loading page without moving to the home screen

Comment: You're not really set any duration for your loading() screen. Can you update the code where you've tried it

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: Can you change order like this 'await   Loading().then ((value) => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {}))
'

Comment: getting an error on the then @Emre

Comment: im getting really confused. Can you please type out the code for what you mean @Emre

Comment: I will update is as soon as possible

Comment: Sorry I didnt had time to look at it, hope you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

What you can do rather is route to the Loader page on button press but add the following code to the Login page code:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), toNext);
  }

  void toNext() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homepage');
  }
```

Comment: you mean landing page

Comment: Yeah on the Loading() page

Comment: Still not working